# Credentials in Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have the following Desired State Configuration (DSC)

```
Configuration Cert
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()] 
        [System.String] $machineName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [PSCredential]
        $certCredential
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration, xCertificate

    Node $machineName 
    {
        xPfxImport cert
        {
            Ensure = 'Present'
            Path = 'C:\certificate.pfx'
            Thumbprint = 'abcdefg'
            Location = 'LocalMachine'
            Store = 'My'
            Exportable = $true
            Credential = $certCredential
        }
    } 
}  
$cd = @{
    AllNodes = @(
    @{
        NodeName = 'localhost'
        PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
    }
)
```

}

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('x', $secpasswd)

Cert -machineName MyPC -certCredential $mycreds -ConfigurationData $cd

Start-DscConfiguration –Path .\Cert –Wait –Verbose -Force
```

When I try to execute this I get the following error:

> ConvertTo-MOFInstance : System.InvalidOperationException error processing property 'Credential' OF TYPE 'xPfxImport': 
>   Converting and storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For more information on securing credentials in 
>   MOF file, please refer to MSDN blog: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729
>   At C:\Users\x\Desktop\script.ps1:18 char:9
>   +   xPfxImport
>   At line:341 char:16
>   +     $aliasId = ConvertTo-MOFInstance $keywordName $canonicalizedValue
>   +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToProcessProperty,ConvertTo-MOFInstance
>   Compilation errors occurred while processing configuration 'Cert'. Please review the errors reported in error stream and 
>   modify your configuration code appropriately.
>   At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\PSDesiredStateConfiguration.psm1:3917 
>   char:5
>   +     throw $ErrorRecord
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Cert:String) [], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToProcessConfiguration

I realize that the password must be encrypted and saving it as plain is not allowed or at least not recommended. I have tried many things suggested in the internet and I am still not able to make this working properly.

I am looking for a way to install a certificate and give certain set certificate permissions after that.

Comment: Actually it is on a new line, I have problems with the formatting at stackoverflow

Comment: Probably not => The term 'PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: try this `$cd` (check updated answer) or change to nodename to reflect your nodename `MyPC`

Comment: Thank you. The last comment led me to the real problem. I did not realize that the nodename is actually what causing the issue. Please change `node localhost` line (8) to `Node $AllNodes.NodeName` and `NodeName="*"` back to `NodeName="localhost"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allow for `plaintextcredentials` ([link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2015/12/18/using-credentials-with-psdscallowplaintextpassword-and-psdscallowdomainuser-in-powershell-dsc-configuration-data/))

```
Configuration DomainCredentialExample
{
param(
    [PSCredential]$DomainCredential
)
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $AllNodes.NodeName
    {
        Group DomainUserToLocalGroup
        {
            GroupName        = 'InfoSecBackDoor'
            MembersToInclude = 'contoso\notyouraccount'
            Credential       = $DomainCredential
        }
    }
}

$cd = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName="localhost"
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword=$true
        }
    )
}

$cred = Get-Credential -UserName contoso\genericuser -Message "Password please"
DomainCredentialExample -DomainCredential $cred -ConfigurationData $cd
```

Comment: This was the first thing I have tried. I still get the same error.

Comment: well, you obviously haven't tried properly, that's how it works, are you sure you did this exactly: `DomainCredentialExample -DomainCredential $cred -ConfigurationData $cd`

Comment: I know this is out of scope of this question but do you have any idea how to give read permissions of that certificate for the `Network Service` user => https://gyazo.com/a32d78823d117306593cba6b613f8489

Comment: never tried doing that, but something like this would help http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/change-file-system-permissions-dsc-powershell,2-1095.html

Comment: This solution works, but don't gloss over the "PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true" line in $cd.

Answer (score 5):

Having found myself facing the same issue, and I just thought I would re-iterate the *actual* cause of the issue (which is actually tucked away in the comments):

> The last comment led me to the real problem. I did not realize that the nodename is actually what causing the issue. Please change node localhost line (8) to Node $AllNodes.NodeName and NodeName="*" back to NodeName="localhost"

Picking through the framework code inside `PSDesiredStateConfiguration.psm1`, the `PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword` flag won't get seen unless `$machineName = localhost` (in our case it was actually a case of fully-qualified vs. non-fully-qualified machine names).

I did also stumble across an undocumented workaround (not that I necessarily recommend using it) - it is actually possible to turn off the check for plaintext credentials using the following registry keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC]
"PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword"="True"
"PSDscAllowDomainUser"="True"
```

Hopefully this might save someone else some head-scratching!